# Как создать собственный браузерный WYSIWYG редактор?

Tags: javascript, html, редактор, wysiwyg, редактор-текста

### Предыстория

Пару лет назад меня здесь, на StackOverflow немного засмеяли за то, что поставил перед собой задачу за нереальный срок создать собственный браузерный текстовый редактор и провалил её (кто засмеял, то меня узнает). Но всё же по сей день не могу понять один странный парадокс: на дворе 2020 год, бум браузерных приложений, JavaScript - самый популярный язык в мире, а до сих пор нет устоявшихся методологий создания собственных браузерных текстовых редакторов с произвольным функционалом. При таком темпе развития JavaScript уже нативно должна предоставлять средства для быстрого крафтинга браузерных WYSIWYG-редакторов, тем не менее, ничего подобного не наблюдается, а существующие редакторы реализованы какими-то извращенскими методами.

### Вопрос

Итак, стандартная для 2020 года задача: нужно создать браузерный WYSIWYG-редактор с набором функционала, соответствующим произвольному техническому заданию, при этом ничего, кроме того, что затребовано, быть не должно. В общем случае, ни один из существующих редакторов не имеет такой гибкости, чтобы подогнать его под данное техническое задание. Не только поведение, но также дизайн, иконки и прочее - всё это должно полностью соответствовать дизайну.

Что же делать? С чего начать? Какие статьи читать? Какие книги покупать? Запереться на несколько месяцев в комнате и заниматься творческим кодизвратом - единственный способ справиться этой, казалось бы, стандартной с точки зрения заказчиков задачей в 2020 году? Это мы знаем про ограничения `textarea`, но если встать на сторону заказчиков, то тут будет лёгкий ступор: как это так - фроентенд разработчик, а не может сделать простенький, но соответствующий техническому заданию редактор?

Comment: Иконки, дизайн. Сфотографируйте задание и картинкой выложите, кликабельные зоны отметьте и все) В чем собственно проблема то? Чего не хватает? Какой функционал не получается реализовать?

Comment: @Leonid, задания пока ещё нет, но я думаю о том, что будет, если в будущем будет запрошено создание WYSIWYG-редактора на заказ. "В чем собственно проблема то?" - Если нужна конкретика, то начнём с самого простого случая: как сделать textara, в которой можно при вводе выделять текст жирным и курсивом?

Comment: При вводе? После ввода текста выделить кусок и сделать его курсивом или жирным? Или установить режим ввода "жирный" и вводить сразу жирный текст?

Comment: @Leonid, Рассмотрим случай с установкой режима ввода "жирный". Если после ввода текста, то тогда можно содержимое textarea преобразовать в div, а дальше выделенный текст обернуть в `b` или стилизованный `span` относительно легко.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работает как указание режима ввода, так и редактирование уже введенного текста. При выделении текста сбрасываются все режимы. Таким образом можно назначить куску текста стиль или отменить вторым нажатием.

Все вводимые символы (соответсвующие регулярке) оборачиваются в `span`. Только так можно обеспечить возможность перекрестных стилей. То есть **ВО*ТТ***АК.

Курсор всегда перебрасывается в конец для простоты (ведь и `span`'ы добавляются в конец). Этот момент надо доработать.

В такое `contenteditable` элемент можно вставлять изображения, списки и вообще все, что душе угодно.

```js
let modeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('mode');
let text = document.getElementById('text');
let modeClass = '';
let selRange = null;

[...modeButtons].forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('active');
    modeClass = ([...modeButtons].map(b => b.classList.contains('active') ? b.getAttribute('data-font') : '')).join(' ');
    if(selRange){
      if(selRange.commonAncestorContainer == text){
        let spans = [...text.getElementsByTagName('span')];
        let start = spans.indexOf(selRange.startContainer.parentElement);
        let end = spans.indexOf(selRange.endContainer.parentElement);
        for(let i = start; i <= end; i++){
          if(b.classList.contains('active')){
            spans[i].classList.add(b.getAttribute('data-font'));
          } else {
            spans[i].classList.remove(b.getAttribute('data-font'));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

})

text.onkeypress = e => {
  if(/[a-zA-Z0-9,.А-ЯЁа-яё]/u.test(e.key.toString()) && e.key != 'Enter'){
    e.preventDefault();

    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = e.key;
    span.className = modeClass;
    e.target.append(span);
  
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.collapse(span, 1);
  }
}

text.onmouseup = e => {
  let sel = window.getSelection();
  if(sel.type == 'Range'){
selRange = sel.getRangeAt(0);
[...modeButtons].forEach(b => {b.classList.remove('active')});
modeClass = '';
  } else {
selRange = null;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#text {
  width: calc(100vw - 10);
  min-height: 40px;
  outline: 1px solid lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.boldi {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cursiv {
  font-style: italic;
}

.underli {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"></div>
<button data-font="boldi" class="mode">Жирно</button>
<button data-font="cursiv" class="mode">Курсив</button>
<button data-font="underli" class="mode">Подчеркн</button>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Значит основной инструмент - атрибут `contenteditable`...